# Fermi's golden rule and the DoS of scattering states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, approximations, density-of-states, fermis-golden-rule

Can the [Fermi's golden rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi's_golden_rule)

$$\Gamma_{fi} ~=~ \rho(E_f) \frac{2\pi}{\hbar} |M_{fi}|^2$$

be applied for transitions of discrete states to scattering states? If yes, then what should the density of states of a scattering state be (i.e. the energy can vary continuously; e.g. a free particle)?

Comment: Is the question somehow unclear? Please leave some feedback after downvoting.

Comment: Possibly my pedagogical paper is helpful. http://arxiv.org/abs/1604.06916